# Message forwarding does not work on particular messages

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I've found out that some Obj-C messages do no get properly forwaded when an object does not explicity handle them.

Here's an example:

Create a new UITableView like:

```
UITableView *v ? [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

Then create an instance of an NSObject with the following methods:

```
(A) - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:");
    return 1;
}
(B) - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:");
    return nil;
}
- (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    NSLog(@"methodSignatureForSelector: %@", NSStringFromSelector(aSelector));
    return [NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes:"@@:@"];
}
- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation {
    NSLog(@"forwardInvocation: %@", NSStringFromSelector(anInvocation.selector));
}
```

Let's call this object ds and set it as the dataSource for the table view:

```
v.dataSource = ds;
```

And when you run your code you should see that both methods (A) and (B) get called by the table view in the expected order:

```
LOG: tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:
LOG: tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

Now it will get interesting, try removing (or just change the name of) method (A), and you should get:

```
LOG: methodSignatureForSelector: tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:
LOG: forwardInvocation: tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:
```

Which is fine because the table view tries to call the **tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:** and since the method is not there, the message gets forwarded to **forwardInvocation:**

Apparently, this is the default behavior for all messages that reference a method that is not defined at an object.

However try restoring the (A) method and removing (B), and you should get:

```
LOG: tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:
```

... and an error telling you that **tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:** was called but didn't return a cell.

For some reason **tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:** gets called (or not) but without following the expected **forwardInvocation:** pathway.

Is this a bug?

Am I doing something wrong?

Are there some messages that explicitly do not get forwarded?

---

Even though **respondsToSelector:** should return FALSE to both functions, somewhere in the implementation sends the message for **cellForRowAtIndexPath:** to some other object and breaks the default *expected* behavior...

What I've learned is basically:

If you are planning to respond to a message in your object, even through some implementation of **forwardInvocation:**, you should **ALWAYS** overload the **respondsToSelector:** method and return TRUE for all messages you plan to implement in your object.

Comment: This is in the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtForwarding.html

Comment: Also, you're not supposed to put the answer inside the question. If you want to answer your own question you add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The runtime system forwards messages only if it's unable to find a match for the given selector in the target class or any of its ancestors. However if the runtime system's search for the selector *succeeds*, it then invokes the method's implementation directly -- no need for forwarding.

By the way, if the lookup fails, the runtime system calls `forwardingTargetForSelector:` first; it then calls `forwardInvocation:` only if `forwardingTargetForSelector:` returns either `nil` or `self`.

Comment: Not the answer 'per se', but definitely pointed me in the right direction and solved it, thanks!

Comment: @almosnow Looks like you accepted this while I was typing. My answer has an additional interesting observation.

Answer (score 2):

The following is my hypothesis based on some experimentation:

The difference is that the table view doesn't attempt to call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` if it isn't defined, whereas it does attempt to call `numberOfRowsInSection`. Therefore, you only see the forwarding mechanism with `numberOfRowsInSection`. The error telling you a cell wasn't returned is just poorly worded and slightly misleading.

I came to this conclusion by observing that, if the data source doesn't define `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, the implementation on `UITableViewController` gets called instead. So, the table view is clearly checking for existence. Therefore, it stands to reason that what happens is something like this:

1. Call on `dataSource` if defined
2. Otherwise, call on `UITableViewController` if defined
3. Otherwise, don't call anything

If (3) is reached, then somewhere downstream an error is thrown because the table view's internal cell variable is `nil`.

Comment: Yep, apparently UITableView does some weird stuff behind the scenes, I've upvoted you so you'll get some rep too. Thanks!